# Autofill on Safari 11 is filling random fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, safari, autofill

So I have this web page where I can select a record from a grid and edit it in a pop-up dialog (all made with ExtJS 3), and after upgrading my MacOS to v10.13 (which includes the new Safari 11 version), one of the fields in that dialog is getting populated with a value of 1 (also with a yellow background, indicating that this has been filled with a pre-saved value), whereas the actual field value is 10, and when I choose to save the edited values for this object, this particular value is always overwritten, and I have to specifically set it to 10 on each edit in order not to lose the current value. The strange thing is that this is only happening when I choose to save my password for this website, and if I don't have the password saved, the field is not getting auto-populated.

I know that this has something to do with the Safari Autofill functionality, what I can't figure out is why from all the fields in all my web application, this is the one that has this problem. I do want to save my user and pass, and have them autofill on login, but I don't want any other fields to be populated, let alone with a wrong value.

Is there a way for me to determine why this field is behaving in such a way, and whether there is a way to prevent this from happening?